# Angular 14 how to convert observable<number> to number

Tags: angular, ngrx

So in my component I have :

```
 constructor(private store: Store, private basketStore: Store<{ basket: Photo[] }>) { }
 position$! :Observable<number>;

 RemoveFromBasket(photo: Photo) {
 
  this.position$ = this.basketStore.select(basketPosition(photo.id));
 
  this.basketStore.dispatch(getBasket({ id: this.position$}));

 }
```

I receive a red line under the id paramater for the dispatch to getBasket stating that `type observable<number> isn't assignable to number`.

My basketPosition Selector looks like:

```
export interface basketSelection {
  basket: Photo[];
}
export const selectPosition = (state: basketSelection) => state.basket;

export const basketPosition = (id: number) => createSelector(selectPosition,
  (basket: Array<Photo>) => { return basket.findIndex(m => m.id == id) }
  )
```

and my reducer:

```
on(getBasket, (state, { id }) =>  state.slice(id)
```

**** Update *****

using @nate-kumar answer.

In my basket I have:

[image]

You can see that I have 2 items with an Id of 5. When I select to delete one of the items with id 5. (photo.id = 5) When I come out of the `RemoveFromBasket` function My state now looks like:

[image]

So Slice seems to have removed first 2 items because the first photo with an id of 5 was at position 2. I changed my slice to be `state.slice(id,1)` but that just removes everything from the basket.

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe to your observable to dispatch the action when the observable emits a value.

```
this.position$ = this.basketStore.select(basketPosition(photo.id));
 
this.position$
  .pipe(
    take(1)  // Unsubscribes after 1 emission, which works perfectly with click events, where you want to trigger an action only once
  )
  .subscribe(
    (id: number) => {
      this.basketStore.dispatch(getBasket({ id }));
    }
  )
```

Comment: Could you take a look at my updated question.  I'm clearly doing something wrong with slice, but not sure what.

Comment: I would use `filter` over `slice` here, so that you can remove all items with the same id in one go. `on(getBasket, (state, { id }) =>  state.filter(item => item.id !== id)`. You're going to have problems if you're building a system where the ids are allowed to be non-unique.

Comment: I used that first, but I dont want to remove all items. only 1. i.e. the user adds 2 of the same item to the basket, but then decide's they only want one of those items, they should just be able to remove that one and not have to remove all then add again.

Answer (score 0):

You can architect this is a better way, the component doesn't need and shouldn't have all of this logic in it.

You just want to say 'do this' in the component by way of action and the reducer should sort the rest out.

This also avoids the manual `subscribe` and rxjs logic.

```
//Action
const removeBasket = createAction('Remove Basket', props<id: string>());
...
// Component
removeFromBasket(photo: Photo) {
  this.store.dispatch(removeBasket({ id: photo.id });
}
...
// Reducer
on(getBasket, (state, { id }) =>  state.filter(item => item.id !== id)
// or whatever you want to do with basketPosition(..)
```

Comment: Yes, Originally, I did not have a selector I just used a reducer with filter. But the issue was if I placed 2 items in the basket of the same type, then when I filter it removed both, but I only want to remove 1. The user may have decided that they only want 1 as opposed to 2 for example and I dont think they should have to add the original agaim

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference, whatever your removal logic is, if it was in the component it can be moved to the reducer where it should be.

Comment: Yes, what I really need to do is work out how to remove 1 record only, which I cannot do with filter. Slice also seems to be an issue.

Comment: I don't want to make things more complicated by recommending a new tool, but for managing lists there is https://ngrx.io/guide/entity